# Sudden JavaScript issues on Joomla 2.5 Website

Tags: javascript, jquery, joomla2.5, mootools

I have a website using Joomla 2.5 and a high number of Plugins and components. I did not change a thing, but since this morning the following happens: The page is rendered fine, and after some seconds delay the page disappears and only one (or several, if available) banner of that page remain. This only happens with javascripted banner items, not with regular image banners. Pages with more than only one banner collapse and show all these banners (without the rest of the page).

What could potentially cause that error, and where to look for rectification?

Thanks for any idea anyone may have.
Ralph

Example:
[enter link description here](http://www.golfanatics.de/anzeigen-sonstiges.html)

Comment: You have a number of JavaScript errors on the page, possibly related to Mootools conflicts. Try disabling the RokAjaxSearch module, then clear site cache.

Comment: Hi, just disabled the RokAjaxSearch and cleared cache, but no changes. .. I leave it like this for reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was solved by the programmers of the main site software JReviews, they "reverted a change that was made to a slider to fix an issue with jQuery 1.11 which is loaded by the latest Joomla 3.2."

I hope this explanation is helpful for the StackExchange forum, and also sufficient, as I do not have further details of the error rectification that was done remotely. Should I get any further details, I will surely post it here.